# asp.net asynchronously execute the tasks and update UI

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-2, parallel-processing

I am developing an asp.net application which will discover UDP clients available on LAN. I need to update UI control(where the discovered devices will be displayed)  and progress bar at the bottom.

The UI control should be updated as the the devices are discovered.

I need to know which method is the best either using Html5 websockets or asp.net asynchronous pages?
if  using asp.net synchronous pages ho can i update UI as i discover nodes

Regards,
Abdul khaliq

Answer (score 0):

Will the discovery code be running serverside or client side?

If serverside you coul use setIntervall or setTimeout to repeatedly call the server for an update on the discovery but that requires the dicovery process to run seperate from the webserver.

Comment: if i run the discover code separate from the webserver how will i update the UI

Comment: You could use a database to store the results from the discovery process and have a small serverside script that is called to get the reslts to the webpage.

Comment: If the server is asp.net  the discovery thread could be spawned from a webpage. On thing to remember, most servers will only process ONE script from each client, so having one ajax call running the scan and using another to fetch results might not wotk as the discovery thread could block re response call.